How not to download junk from Gmail
I have a Gmail account configured on Mail.app.
Over the years I have marked junk as junk, report as junk, and block on Gmail.
When I read that account using Mail.app, I still see the same junk in the Inbox and sometimes in the All Junk box.
Is there a way to force Mail.app to refrain from downloading that?
Yes, I have more than 1000 junk filters on Mail.app but my point is not to download that from Gmail. Thanks

When you “report junk,” is the mail message moved to the Junk folder?

yes, but days later, if the same moron sends a mail it may appear in the inbox or in the All Junk folder in the Mail.app.
